# Is there anyway to generate coverage reports on sonar?

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm working iOs app,which uses swift language.It's generating coverage.profdata successfully.But I would like to generate the same thing on SonarQube.
Please let me know if you have any ideas!!
I tried the below link
[swift-sonar properties](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift/blob/master/sonar-project.properties)

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube Swift plugin does not have built-in support to import coverage results.

The only option (and the best one) for you is to use the [Generic Coverage Plugin](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/genericcoverage.html):

- First you run your coverage tool to generate the coverage.profdata file
- Then you manage to transform this file into the target format supported by the Generic Coverage Plugin
- And finally you reference this new coverage file in your sonar-project.properties file (like explained in the documentation of the plugin)